# With n a positive integer, evaluate the sum

Tags: combinatorics

With $n$ a positive integer, evaluate the sum

$$\binom{n}{0}-3\binom{n}{1}+3^2\binom{n}{2}+\cdots+(-1)^n3^n\displaystyle\binom{n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-3)^k\binom{n}{k}$$

Anyone know how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of binomial coefficients, $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}x^k=(1+x)^n.$$ For your problem, take $x=-3$ to conclude the sum is $(-2)^n$.

Comment: How did you come up with the value x=-3?

Comment: @Aaron, JohnD guessed it.The whole thing is pretty obvious once you recognize a pattern-a binomial expansion.

Comment: Look at the terms in your sum: the binomial coefficients are being multiplied by $(-3)^k$, $k=0,1,2,\dots,n$ each time.

Comment: Can you explain the alternating postive and negative sign? Or is it just for the second term

Comment: @Aaron: $(-3)^n=(-1)^n\cdot 3^n$, that's why you are seeing the alternating signs and increasing powers of 3.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that
$$(1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}k (-x)^k$$